# What is the difference between MyEnum.Item.ToString() and nameof(MyEnum.Item)?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

```
MyEnum.Item.ToString();
nameof(MyEnum.Item);
```

Which style is preferred? Is there any practical difference between the two?

Comment: The ToString() version is pretty expensive.  The nameof version is going to give you a very unpleasant surprise when you change the enum declaration but only deployed a bug fix that did not update all assemblies that use it.

Comment: @HansPassant, would you care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @PauloMorgado nameof is done when the dll is compiled, so if you defined the enum in project A, and in project B you do `nameof(MyEnum.Item)`, the `nameof(..)` would be replaced with `"Item"`, if you changed project A's enum from `Item` to `Banana`, unless you recompile project B, it will still be `Item`. In the real world this almost never happens cos the consuming app would be recompiled. People shouldn't be dropping in dll's willy nilly.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first is a run-time call that will realise at runtime it needs to return the string `"Item"`, and do so.

The second is another way to write `"Item"` straight into the code.

The second would be slightly faster, but prior to C#6 would not have been available. To put `"Item"` in the code manually would have therefore been an optimisation that risked an error, while `nameof()` would catch such an error at compile-time.

As such while the approach of using the name directly might once have been considered taking a risk, that risk is gone, and it has a slight edge.

`ToString()` though remains the only way to output the string based on a variable or expression of the `MyEnum` type.

Comment: Just to underline what Jon says: this function would return 'color', not the result of color.ToString().    `string GetText (System.ConsoleColor color){
 return nameof(color);
}`

Answer (score 10):

`.ToString()` is evaluated at runtime and can be called with [your own format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0h36syw(v=vs.110).aspx).

`nameof()` is evaluated at compile-time and will inject a string literal that will never change.

Comment: So that makes nameof() a bit faster since no function call during execution.

Comment: How do you override the `ToString()` of an enum?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not obfuscating your code, pretty much the same... the moment you obfuscate your code however, `ToString()` will likely produce garbage, while `nameof()` will retrieve the name you requested / expected.

More info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)