# Automated refactor of MyEnum.MyValue.ToString() to nameof(MyEnum.MyValue)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

All throughout our codebase, we use syntax like:

```
MyEnum.MyValue.ToString()
```

to get the string value "MyValue" from

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    MyValue,
    ...
}
```

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35523244/2343739), I would like to refactor these calls to use the compile-time, more performant `nameof()` syntax like below:

```
nameof(MyEnum.MyValue)
```

Is there a way to use ReSharper, Visual Studio, etc. to assist with this refactor? I am currently using the latest version of both products, and I am not provided with any tooltips by default to perform this refactor. The only thing I can think of is using a custom regex find-and-replace. I would welcome a regex answer, but I was hoping for something simpler.

Update: The names `MyEnum` and `MyValue` are just for an example. I am looking for a generalized solution that would apply to all enum names and enum value names.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Did you try to search-and-replace as explicit as possible? I think a simple string replace should work as your string `MyEnum.MyValue.ToString()` seems kind of unique enough.

Comment: Yeah, search and replace could work, but would require either some fancy regex (which I'm open to, I am just no good at regex) or completely unique find and replace values for each enum value.

Comment: "...or completely unique find and replace values for each enum value" - that seems to be the safest and easiest thing to do. How many values does your enum have?

Comment: Question: why do you want to do this? There's no real difference.

Comment: Replacing `MyEnum.MyValue.ToString()` with `nameof(MyEnum.MyValue)` is no good? I don't think regex is necessary here. I think that can only cause inconsistency in the `using`s.

Comment: @DavidG because you can refactor your code better when you use `nameof` trust me.

Comment: @Meikel no offense, but I would venture a guess that DavidG is a more trustworthy source

Comment: @Meikel I'm well aware of that (I'm a C# gold badge holder on here!), but doing this just for the sake of future refactoring isn't a strong proposition in my book.

Comment: @DavidG: It's also faster (compile-time instead of runtime).

Comment: @SLaks True, but we're almost certainly talking micro-optimisations here. The amount of effort fixing hundreds of these in a large code base is likely more time than would be saved at compile and run time :)

Comment: @SLaks that is the only true advantage I have read in this comment chain so far.  I would still call that a micro optimization though

Comment: This refactor is certainly not a top priority. But, as I am resolving issues, I like to do cleanup as well within the code I am touching. I use VS and ReSharper suggestions to do this all the time for other issues, and was hoping for something similar. My intention is not to do a one-time global find-and-replace, but on the fly as I am working in the areas around these calls.

Comment: @CollinM.Barrett Since you brought up performance, this is always a useful read https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/