# How to pass Enum as string parameter to Authorize attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity

It's my first project to ASP.NET Core Authentication and Authorization and I get this error when I'm trying to pass Enum to [Authorize] attribute :

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'BasicAuthAPI.Entities.Role' to
> 'string'

Here is my controller method which gives this error:

```
[Authorize(Role.Admin)]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
     var users = _userService.GetAll();
     return Ok(users);
}
```

Role enum:

```
public enum Role
    {
        Admin,
        User
    }
```

User Entity:

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    }
```

And the _userService which I have mentioned in controller:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private DataContext _context;
        private IJwtUtils _jwtUtils;
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public UserService(
            DataContext context,
            IJwtUtils jwtUtils,
            IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _context = context;
            _jwtUtils = jwtUtils;
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }


        public AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == model.Username);

            // validate
            if (user == null || !BCryptNet.Verify(model.Password, user.PasswordHash))
                throw new AppException("Username or password is incorrect");

            // authentication successful so generate jwt token
            var jwtToken = _jwtUtils.GenerateJwtToken(user);

            return new AuthenticateResponse(user, jwtToken);
        }

        public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Users;
        }

        public User GetById(int id)
        {
            var user = _context.Users.Find(id);
            if (user == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException("User not found");
            return user;
        }
    }
```

How can I pass the Admin Role to [Authorize] attribute?

Comment: Do you intend to pass it as a role to Authorize attribute or as the authorization policy name? It is currently expecting that what you pass is the authorization policy name.

Answer (score 3):

Either use string constants

```
public static class Role
{
    public static string Admin = "Admin";
    public static string User = "User";
}
```

or you can use `nameof`

```
[Authorize(nameof(Role.Admin))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `.ToString()`

```
[Authorize(Role.Admin.ToString())]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
     var users = _userService.GetAll();
     return Ok(users);
}
```

Looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392697/9916400) from Alexander I have found the following SO post which highlights the difference between `nameof` and `ToString`: [What is the difference between MyEnum.Item.ToString() and nameof(MyEnum.Item)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523172/what-is-the-difference-between-myenum-item-tostring-and-nameofmyenum-item)

Comment: .ToString() gives me Compiler Error CS0182.

Comment: Using  string constants gives errors from other classes where Role class is injected. Use of nameof returns this message in Postman after trying to authorize:                        
"message": "The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Admin' was not found.". Looking for other solutions

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any possible solution?